# Issue with json response in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, devise

I have an issue with rails and devise logging me out everytime i request a .json extension file.

For example . I have a list of tables and everytime i check /tables.json in the browser it displays the data but when i go back to the root folder it logs me out.

I don't know what to do to make this work.

Here is my index controller for tables

```
def index
    @table = current_user.seating.tables
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => @table.to_json }
    end

end
```

Comment: The problem is not in this snippet. Anything else you could post?

Comment: Hi, can you give me any pointers on what part of the code you think i should post here? Sorry.. I am a bit of a noob with all this.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with devise. I have never used that, so I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

@table is where I think your problem is. What is displayed in your view if you add

```
<%= @table %>
```

to your tables/index.html.erb file?

I find that with devise current_user often runs into different issues.

To debug, I would start with changing

```
current_user.seating.tables
```

to

```
get_tables(current_user.id)
```

and define to method inside your table model looking something like:

```
def get_tables(user_id)
  *Whatever logic to call tables, by using the 'user_id' goes here*
end
```